# Git and push/pull auth: i accidentally entered my password instead of the username

Tags: git, authentication, github

## What I did

So, it was a sunny, calm summer day, when I whipped out the PyCharm terminal to enter the sweet little command: `git push`. Most likely because I recently installed the OS, and it didn't even know who I am on GitHub, as I didn't pull or push since the very installation. It used `ksshaskpass` to ask me for the username. It said "password for https://github.com". That moment I probably was a bit tired, so I entered my GH password. Uh oh, and it asks me for a password for https://<my password>@github.com. A moment of realization: it asked me for a username/PAT combo.

**TL;DR** I tried to push to GitHub but was asked by `ksshaskpass` for a username, specifically for "password for https://github.com". Mistakenly, I entered my GitHub password and was prompted for a password for https://<my password>@github.com. It then dawned on me that I needed to provide a username/PAT combo instead.

## What happened

It was actually asking for a username, but `ksshaskpass` said "password", so I entered my password. And it asks for a password for https://<my password>@github.com.

## What I did to solve it

I just entered my PAT, and it worked. Well, easy. *100% solution, almost...*

## And now, what's the problem?

Somewhere, it stores an HTTPS address (https://<my password>@github.com) with my password in plain text. If this leaks somewhere, well... So, I need to get rid of this thing.

## What I did to solve the actual problem (HTTPS address)?

1. `git credential reject`. Simple, yet not working.
2. `rm -f ~/.gitconfig ; rm -rf ~/.git`. Didn't help either.

## System stuff

**Git version:** git version 2.41.0

**System specs:**

```
OS: Fedora Linux 38 (KDE Plasma) x86_64 
Host: MS-7D18 2.0 
Kernel: 6.4.6-200.fc38.x86_64 
Uptime: 25 mins 
Packages: 2015 (rpm), 13 (flatpak) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 5.27.6 
WM: kwin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: tmux 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11400 (12) @ 4.400GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate 
Memory: 4229MiB / 15875MiB
```

Comment: Change your password.  Right now. Scrapers and such may already have this information stored in a database.

Comment: To be less alarmist: did the pull fail? From reading, it seems like your password is stored in plain text, but only on your local machine?

Comment: It may be stuck in a git remote (unlikely, but `git remote -v` would show if that's the case. and otherwise, since `ksshaskpass` seems to use KWallet, to you may want to look there and remove the bad entry.

Answer (score 0):

Credential Manager will help you in that. Just delete them from here and all will be perfect. You will be asked one more time to enter the username and password.

Comment: I did that. I did `git credential reject`. And `git credential-cache exit`. And even `git credential-cache erase`.